# c3 chart: error when data comes from url

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I am finding this error every time I try to plot data from a `url`... I have read some blogs saying they had the same problem, but I do not have the answer yet, any help?

```
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    url: 'static/CSV/Chart_data/grade_year.csv'
  }
});
</script>
```

and the `grade_year` is:

```
AC_YEAR,Calculus I
2010,5.718
2011,6.052
2012,5.29
2013,5.238
2014,5.037
2015,4.919
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
c3.js:5388 Uncaught TypeError: $$.d3.request is not a function
    at ChartInternal.c3_chart_internal_fn.convertUrlToData
    at ChartInternal.c3_chart_internal_fn.init (c3.js:1068)
    at new Chart (c3.js:1018)
    at Object.c3.generate (c3.js:1043)
```

Comment: You're using D3 v5 reference. Change it to v4.

Comment: Hey @GerardoFurtado thank you! Can you further explain how to do it? Thanks!!

Comment: You have a reference to D3 somewhere in your html. Look at it, then change `v5` for `v4`.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!! @GerardoFurtado